# Pitfalls of renaming tables in sql server

Tags: sql-server, load

I've thought of an approach for a process that builds a fairly large table (2million rows), now I'm canvassing opinion for it.  What's going to bite me with this renaming approach to a making a table 'live'?

Background:
The table (data.CatExt) is an overlayed version of our product catalogue. It builds daily in a complex procedure (getting data from lots of different areas and deciding which source trumps when there are conflicts - the complexity is in the business logic, not the technological side).  All the work and any tables required to get the final output happen in a 'build' schema, and the final table lives in the 'data' schema.  The schemas have different permissions.

The table is pretty wide, about 100 fields. We've taken the approach of building it from scratch each day, rather than using a 'change/additions/deletions' approach, because of the nature of the data sources (horrible to work out what is going to require a change to the final table.)  So we build a new version of the table each day, and then (after it passes some automated checks) allow that to become the new live version.

New approach:
So here's where the new approach comes in.  What's the best way to replace the live version? The simplest option is to truncate and replace with the new data, but that seems like a lot of writing of data unnecessarily. We could do an update over each field, but with 100 fields that's a lot of nasty coding/comparison to find any differences.  So I thought, why not rename the table?  It would go like this:

1. Live version data.CatExt exists and is useable through steps 2 and 3.
2. Build new version of the table build.CatExt.
3. Checks, indexing etc over build.CatExt all complete - ie, it's perfect.
4. Drop (well, I'm too chicken - probably rename) data.CatExt, rename build.CatExt to data.CatExt.

Voila, new version, no unnecessary moving of data and associated long time while the live version is being locked.

Please point out the flaws. (Be gentle, I'm new! :) )

Comment: This is something we do quite often. You should definitely make sure the drop/renames are all within one transaction. Building and populating can be done outside of the transaction

Comment: I do something like this but instead of drop/rename I use multiple schemas to transfer objects. See [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo) and [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2). I've also talked around this in multiple answers, including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9187027/61305) and [this one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31668/1186).

Comment: @Aaron - your links pointed me in exactly the right direction.  What's the best way to recognise that on this form? Is it bad form to "answer" my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar to [Jason](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105026/1186) - which doesn't require partitioning, by the way - but I use schema transfers instead of switching. It requires two additional schemas to support multiple transfers - in my case I call them `fake` and `shadow`. Basically you empty the shadow table, then populate it (you could also use an `upsert` methodology, but I find truncate/insert to be faster and less complicated, especially for a background process). You can optionally update stats on the shadow copy at this point which, again, is a background process, so won't interrupt your users except in a really overloaded workload. Then you start a transaction, move the production (`dbo`) copy of the table into the fake schema, move the newly populated shadow schema into production, and commit. This is a metadata operation only and will require schema locks but it should happen almost instantaneously. Finally, move the old production copy of the table into the shadow schema (and optionally truncate it now to save space - though I often kept the table populated so I have a backup copy of the last version of the table, just in case).

```
TRUNCATE TABLE shadow.Lookup;

INSERT shadow.Lookup([cols]) 
  SELECT [cols] FROM [source];

-- perhaps an explicit statistics update here

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  ALTER SCHEMA fake TRANSFER     dbo.Lookup;
  ALTER SCHEMA dbo  TRANSFER  shadow.Lookup;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

ALTER SCHEMA shadow TRANSFER fake.Lookup;

-- optionally truncate shadow.Lookup now
```

Not really any advantage of one over the other, but you should read a few of my other posts for more background, some of my reasoning, gotchas, etc. For example, foreign keys will not likely be your friend here - in my scenario this worked best for aggregated, denormalized data, or copies that were being used for read-only workloads (and thus didn't need referential constraints - not that I'm advocating that or anything).

- [T-SQL Tuesday #33 : Trick Shots : Schema Switch-A-Roo](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo)
- [Schema Switch-A-Roo : Part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2)
- My answer to [Most efficient way to move table rows from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9187027/61305)
- My answer to [How much overhead is involved with querying a DB on the same server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31668/1186)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use partition switching once you have both tables set up create a switch out table.

Then do a simple switch command like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table Name] SWITCH
   TO [Table Name]_SwitchOut

ALTER TABLE [Table Name]_SwitchIn SWITCH
   TO [Table Name];
```

Then simply drop the in and out tables.

Comment: I didn't use this option, because (as far as I could figure out), it requires your tables to be partitioned to begin with.

Comment: It does not. You can do it on any table. The switch in and out table must have the same exact schema as the main table. Also the switch in table must have the same indexes as the main table.